# Getting (WARNING: requested port 0 not present - ignoring) while running dpdk

Tags: linux-device-driver, nic, dpdk

I have tried to run dpdk in my redhat6.3 verison.

**Network devices using IGB_UIO driver**

```
====================================
**0000:43:00.0 '82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbe
0000:43:00.1 '82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbe
0000:46:00.0 'Device 155d' drv=igb_uio unused=
0000:46:00.1 'Device 155d' drv=igb_uio unused=**
```

coreId : 5
EAL: Cannot read numa node link for lcore 5 -using physical package id instead
EAL: Detected lcore 5 as core 5 on socket 0
EAL: Setting up hugepage memory...
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2097152 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5483400000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x4290772992 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5383600000 (size = 0xffc00000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2097152 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5383200000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x4294967296 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5283000000 (size = 0x100000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2097152 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5282c00000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x4290772992 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5182e00000 (size = 0xffc00000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2097152 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5182a00000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2097152 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5182600000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x4290772992 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5082800000 (size = 0xffc00000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2097152 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7f5082400000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: Requesting 256 pages of size 2MB from socket 0
EAL: TSC frequency is ~2700001 KHz
EAL: Master core 5 is ready (tid=864ff820)
    EAL: PCI device 0000:43:00.1 on NUMA socket 1
    EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb rte_ixgbe_pmd
    EAL:   PCI memory mapped at 0x7fe900943000
    EAL:   PCI memory mapped at 0x7fe90093f000
    EAL: PCI device 0000:46:00.0 on NUMA socket 1
    EAL:   probe driver: 8086:155d rte_ixgbe_pmd
    EAL:   Device is blacklisted, not initializing
    EAL: PCI device 0000:46:00.1 on NUMA socket 1
    EAL:   probe driver: 8086:155d rte_ixgbe_pmd
    EAL:   Device is blacklisted, not initializing
    WARNING: requested port 0 not present - ignoring
    WARNING: requested port 1 not present - ignoring
    0 [EAL options] -- -p PORTMASK -n NUM_CLIENTS [-s NUM_SOCKETS]
    -p PORTMASK: hexadecimal bitmask of ports to use
    -n NUM_CLIENTS: number of client processes to use
    Process affinity succesffuly set to cpu 5.
    TIME_InitCommon(): Done. TIME_MiliSecPerSysTick=1, TIME_SysTickPerSec=1000.

Ports are there, but still i can't run dpdk using  "0000:43:00.0 '82599EB"

what is the problem ?

Same configuration i am using to run DPDK for 0000:46:00.0 and 0000:43:00.0. but the above 82599EB NIC is not running why?

**The same time Dpdk is able to run with 0000:46:00.0 'Device 155d' [This LOGS are below]**

```
Creating mbuf pool 'MProc_pktmbuf_pool' [46080 mbufs] ...    

Port 0 init ... done:   
Port 1 init ... done:   
Checking link statusdone  
Port 0 Link Up - speed 10000 Mbps - full-duplex     
Port 1 Link Up - speed 10000 Mbps - full-duplex
```

Comment: Looks like the logs are incomplete. Please include complete logs, including the command line arguments you are using to run the DPDK app.

Comment: <imagefile> -coreId 5 -socket 0 -c 20 -n 4 --proc-type=primary --socket-mem=512,0,0,0 -b 0:01:0.0 -b 0:01:0.1 -b 0:01:0.2 -b 0:01:0.3 -b 0:46:0.0 -b 0:46:0.1 -b 0:41:0.0 -b 0:41:0.1 -b 0:07:00.0 -b 0:07:00.1 -b 0:03:0.0 -b 0:03:0.1 -b 0:05:0.0 -b 0:05:0.1 -- -p 3 -n I have blocked all ports (43th port alone memory is created properly but its showing port is note present) (i used to run dpdk by this config file) –

Answer (score 0):

> imagefile -coreId 5 -socket 0 -c 20 -n 4 --proc-type=primary --socket-mem=512,0,0,0 -b 0:01:0.0 -b 0:01:0.1 -b 0:01:0.2 -b 0:01:0.3 -b 0:46:0.0 -b 0:46:0.1 -b 0:41:0.0 -b 0:41:0.1 -b 0:07:00.0 -b 0:07:00.1 -b 0:03:0.0 -b 0:03:0.1 -b 0:05:0.0 -b 0:05:0.1 -- -p 3 -n

There are few problems with the command line:

1. The `-coreId`, `-socket` is not a valid DPDK command line argument. That is probably your app custom arguments?
2. The `--proc-type` is used for multiprocess application, usually we don't need this option.
3. The `--socket-mem=512,0,0,0` allocates 512MB on NUMA node 0 and zero on nodes 1-3. But please note, that some of your NICs are on NUMA node 1 in fact, so we need to allocate some memory there as well.
4. Instead of a bunch of `-b` (blacklist) options we can use  just one or two `-w` (whitelist)

Still it does not explain why there is no `0000:43:00.0` device appeared. So pease try to add `--log-level=debug` to see what is happening to this device.